# Sql query: no rows selected

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I tried different variations of the sql statement but I am still getting "no rows selected". I don't know where I am going wrong!.

Here is the question:

I have to list titles of conferences organized by the employees whose manager is 'Green'.

The tables associated with the query are:

`Employee_C` table:

```
EID  NAME   SALARY           MID
---    -------------------- -----
e01   Wilson    53000
e02   Smith      48000       e01
e03   Jones      38000       e01
e04   Loftus     41000
e05   Fox        54000       e04
e06   Smith      45000       e04
e07   Green      48000
e08   Fox        49000       e04
e09   Wolf       41000       e04
e10   Wang        32000      e01
e11   Phillips    33000      e07
e12   Liu         27000      e07
```

`Conference_C` table:

```
CONFID              TITLE                     LOCATION          SDATE
------        --------------------       -------------------- ---------
c00001    Hydroinformatics                  Singapore          15-JUN-12
c00002    Ecological_modeling               Berlin             15-JUL-12
c00003    Computational_M                   London             25-MAY-12
c00004    Ecoinformatics                    Boston             22-AUG-12
c00005    Uncertainty_analysis              Athens             10-OCT-12
c00006    Large_databases                   Toronto            13-APR-12
c00007    Systems_analysis                  Boston             23-MAR-12
c00008    Systems_integration               Tokyo              24-FEB-12
c00009    Aquatic_biology                   Helsinki           12-MAY-12
c00010    Information_systems               Paris               08-JAN-12
c00011    Simulation_modeling               Rome                01-SEP-12
c00012    DSS                               Melbourne          18-DEC-12
```

`Deals_C` table:

```
EID   CONFID
---    ------
e02   c00001
e03   c00001
e05   c00001
e06   c00001
e03   c00002
e08   c00002
e09   c00002
e10   c00002
e03   c00003
e05   c00003
e06   c00004
e08   c00005
e09   c00005
e10   c00005
e06   c00005
e11   c00006
e12   c00006
e05   c00007
e06   c00007
e08   c00007
e09   c00008
e10   c00008
e11   c00008
e02   c00009
e12   c00009
e10   c00010
e02   c00011
e03   c00011
e05   c00011
e12   c00012
e06   c00012
```

The sql statement that I have is:

```
select C.Title 
from Conference_C C 
where C.ConfID in (select D.ConfID
                   from  Deals_C D 
                   where D.eid in (select E.eid 
                                   from Employee_C E 
                                   where E.Name = 'Green'));
```

I got "no rows selected"

Comment: You don't have and deals with eid = 07.

Comment: Green's EID is e07 and you don't have any row with e07 EID in Deals_C table.

Comment: check my answer why its not returning record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your query is you are checking the wrong employee data. Your `WHERE` clause is checking the `EID` to the `EID` when it really should be checking the `Deals_C.EID` to the `Employees.MID`:

```
select C.Title 
from Conference_C C 
inner join
(
  select D.ConfID, e.eid
  from Deals_C D 
  inner join Employee_C e
    on d.EID= e.EID
  where exists (select *
                from Employee_C e2
                where E2.Name = 'Green'
                  and e.mid = e2.eid)
) d
  on c.CONFID = d.CONFID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45897/6).

The `EXISTS` query is returning the rows that have the last name of `Green` but you need to check the `Employee_C.MID` to the subqueries `EID`.

This can also be written:

```
select C.Title 
from Conference_C C 
where C.ConfID in (select D.ConfID
                   from Deals_C D 
                   inner join Employee_C e
                     on d.EID= e.EID
                   where exists (select *
                                 from Employee_C e2
                                 where E2.Name = 'Green'
                                   and e.mid = e2.eid));
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45897/11)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. The reason I had "no row selected" was simply because my sqlcase was set to UPPER and I was querying in lower case. 
i.e. WHERE empName LIKE '_a%';
I set the sqlcase to mixed and solved my problem. Seems that string between quotes is case sensitive. Hope it helps.